# Writing a ruby file_field in html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, input, filefield

```
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
```

How do I write this in html? I know that it's an input type="file" but how can I put in the :photo? I need to customise the field by writing it in html in rails.

Comment: Why don't you just view the source in your browser? That'll give you the html generated by the helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**f** is the oject name, **photo** is the attribute name, so you have

```
id="object_photo"
name="object[photo]"

<input type="file" size="20" name="object[photo]" id="object_photo">
```